# phtml template is not loading from controller

Tags: magento-1.9

I am new to magento and learning Magento Extension Development. I am trying to load phtml template from controller but it is not loading.

Here is my code:
app/code/local/MasteringMagento/Example/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <module>
    <MasteringMagento_Example>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </MasteringMagento_Example>
  </module>

  <global>
    <models>
      <example>
        <class>MasteringMagento_Example_Model</class>
      </example>
    </models>
    <blocks>
      <example>
        <class>MasteringMagento_Example_Block</class>
      </example>
    </blocks>
    <helpers>
      <example>
        <class>MasteringMagento_Example_Helper</class>
      </example>
    </helpers>
  </global>

  <frontend>
    <routers>
      <example>
        <use>standard</use>
        <args>
          <frontName>example</frontName>
          <module>MasteringMagento_Example</module>
        </args>
      </example>
    </routers>

    <layout>
      <updates>
        <example>
          <file>example.xml</file>
        </example>
      </updates>
    </layout>

  </frontend>
```

app/code/local/MasteringMagento/Example/controllers/HelloController.php

```
<?php

  class MasteringMagento_Example_HelloController
      extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{

      public function worldAction(){
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
      }

  }

?>
```

app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/example.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="1.0">
  <example_hello_world>
    <update handle="page_two_columns_right">
  </example_hello_world>

  <refrence name="content">
    <block type="core/template" name="example" template="example/welcome.phtml" />
  </refrence>

</layout>
```

app/design/frontend/base/default/template/example/welcome.phtml

```
<p>Hello World</p>
```

Please point out that where I made mistake. Thank you

Comment: problem in your example.xml.  <refrence name="content"> should be inside in <example_hello_world> this tag.

Answer (score 2):

in app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/example.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="1.0">
  <example_hello_world>
    <update handle="page_two_columns_right">


  <refrence name="content">
    <block type="core/template" name="example" template="example/welcome.phtml" />
  </refrence>
</example_hello_world>

</layout>
```

Comment: what is the problem in this file? I trie but did not work.

Comment: Did you flushed Magento Cache after making the changes ?

Comment: replace `refrence` with `reference` in your code

Comment: replace example.xml  with my code and clear cache